# ngrx - Make sure all http calls are done & storing in the store

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

**A brief summary of what I want**

- Call api 1
- Call api 2
- Wait until these data are saved in the `store`
- Get these data via on the level of `effect`

**Description**

What I'd like to do is simply wait until some actions are properly finished and stored in store. And then run next one.

For example,

```
@Effect()
  getData1$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.getData1Action),
    switchMap(action => {  // Simply call an api and save data in the store by calling GetData1Success.
      this.httpClient.get(...)
      .pipe(
        map((result) => new GetData1Success(result))
      )
    })
  );
```

```
@Effect()
  someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.UserLogIn),
    flatMap(_ => {  // get first data
      this.store.dispatch(new getData1());
      return of(_);
    }),
    flatMap(_ => {  // get second data
      this.store.dispatch(new getData2());
      return of(_);
    }),
    switchMap(action => { // run final action
      return [new finalAction()];
    }),
    catchError(() => of(new finalActionFailure()))
  );
```

And then `finalAction()` is executed,

```
@Effect()
  finalEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.FinalActionAction),
    switchMap(action => {
      this.store.pipe(select(fromData.data1)).subscribe(data1 => {this.data1 = data1});
      this.store.pipe(select(fromData.data2)).subscribe(data1 => {this.data2 = data2});

  // this.data1, this.data2 are empty...

      return [new finalAction()];
    })
  );
```

In `someEffect$`, both `getData1` and `getData2` are calling http request and store when http call is successfully done.

The problem is that it doesn't wait until data are saved in the store.
And just `finalAction` is executed.

I understand why because `flatMap` wait until `getData1` is done. But not `GetData1Success`.

In this case, how can I get data from store properly at the moment of `finalEffect$`?

Thanks.

EDIT 1: I have already tried using the `forkJoin`. But I have no idea how to catch data when it is stored in the store.

Comment: It's because you're piping off of the http request for your map. That should be moved up to the original pipe

Comment: @Clouse24 Can you tell me more detail? Where is the 'original pipe'?

Comment: take a look at the forkJoin operator

Comment: @timdeschryver I actually tried forkJoin (I used it a lot before use Ngrx). However I have no idea how to solve my issue with forkJoin. In my case, I have to call two Actions. but how can I use forkJoin and catch up those actions are done and data are saved in the store?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve by using `forkJoin`. But not sure if this is a clean way.

Let me know your opinions.

So, my solution was modifying the second code from the above.

```
@Effect()
  someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.UserLogIn),
    switchMap(_ => {
      const data1 = this.httpClient.get(...);
      const data2 = this.httpClient.get(...);

      return forkJoin(data1, data2).pipe(
        tap(
         result => {
          // Here update data to the store.
          this.store.dispatch(GetData1Success(result[0]));
          this.store.dispatch(GetData2Success(result[1]));
         }

        )
      )

    }),
    switchMap(action => { // run final action
      return [new finalAction()];
    }),
    catchError(() => of(new finalActionFailure()))
  );
```

I have already an action called `GetData1` which gets data1 but I couldn't use this action in my case because I have no idea how to catch the moment when data1 is saved in the `store`.

And ended up using `forkJoin` with calling http request manually in the `switchMap`.